# Using wildcards to do mass renaming?

Tags: bash, scripts, rename, mv

I realized I had named a bunch of files in an off-by-one fashion so I wanted to rename any file starting with "1" to the same thing except starting with 2.

For example `mv 1.4.5.txt 2.4.5.txt` or `mv 1-chart.jpg 2-chart.jpg` etc.

I tried `mv 1* 2*` but this was not accepted because it interprets `2*` as a directory.

Comment: Reopen vote: I feel this is missing a generic approach like `rename 's/^[0-9]*/$&+1/e' file` would be.

Comment: @dessert: The accepted answer to the linked question addresses something very similar though. I'm voting to keep this one closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wildcards won't do it. Look at the result of `echo mv 1* 2*`. A better way is (`man rename`):

```
rename 's/^1/2/' 1*
```

Comment: To do it dynamically, use `rename 's/^[0-9]*/$&+1/e' file` instead, this will increase the number at the beginning of the filename by one. Unfortunately the question got closed so that I can't add another answer for that.

Comment: @dessert What about "rename any file starting with "1" to the same thing except starting with 2." says "increment the number at the beginning"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards in that way if you install `mmv` (although they must be quoted - so that they are interpreted by `mmv` itself rather than the shell), and the replacement wildcard takes the form `#n` to re-substitute the n<sup>th</sup> wildcard from the pattern:

```
Usage: mmv [-m|x|r|c|o|a|l] [-h] [-d|p] [-g|t] [-v|n] [from to]

Use #[l|u]N in the ``to'' pattern to get the [lowercase|uppercase of the]
string matched by the N'th ``from'' pattern wildcard.

A ``from'' pattern containing wildcards should be quoted when given
on the command line. Also you may need to quote ``to'' pattern.

Use -- as the end of options.
```

So for example

```
$ mmv -n -- '1*' 2#1
1.sh -> 2.sh : delete old 2.sh? n
1-chart.jpg -> 2-chart.jpg
1.4.5.txt -> 2.4.5.txt
1.csv -> 2.csv
```

(The `-n` option allows you to do a dry-run - remove it to actually rename the files.)